# Init @StateObject that depends on @Environment

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create SwiftUI view that has `@StateObject` inside as a data container, however, it depends on `@Environment` variable.

For sure, I'm doing something wrong but I cannot find an effective solution.

That's how my View looks like:

```
struct SomeView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  @StateObject var myDataContainer: MyDataContainer
  
  init() {
    let context = managedObjectContext
    _weeklyStatistics = StateObject(wrappedValue: StatisticsWeeklyDataContainer(context: context)) // Exception, as we are trying to access managedObjectContext before init
  }
```

I cannot access `self.managedObjectContext` during init, and that fails compilation.

MyDataContainer depends on `NSManagedObjectContext`, which is set as environment variable:

```
class MyDataContrainer: ObservableObject {
  @Published var foo: [Date] = []
  
  private let context: NSManagedObjectContext
  
  init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    self.context = context
    print("myDataContainer init")
  }
```

I'm wondering, how to solve these issues correctly?

Comment: have you tried using `.onAppear{...}` to set/update things?

Comment: Use a parent view which reads the environment. Then, in the body of the parent,  pass the environment value as parameter in the initialiser to the child view `SomeView`. Tip: for purposes like this, you can create a generic "EnvironmentReaderView" making this an idiomatic solution in two lines of code. :)

Comment: `@StateObject` is designed to be a source of truth thus should not have any dependencies.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject#Initialize-state-objects-using-external-data

Comment: @malhal While this is true regarding the data, the environment however might be the provider for dependencies (aka services) which get injected into the StateObject's wrapped value. If you want to utilise dependency injection, how else would you accomplish this in a seamless, concise and cool manner - since SwiftUI provides us all the tools already?

Comment: @CouchDeveloper call the service func from an action and store the result in a state. That way you don't even need a stateobject so don't have the issue of giving it a dependency. Swift is designed to be functional like this, not object oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two approaches you can use.

1. As alluded to in the comments, you can use `task` or `onAppear` to update your `ObservableObject`. However, this means that the property must be an `Optional`, since it will not exist at `init`

```
class MyDataContainer: ObservableObject {
   var context: NSManagedObjectContext?
} 

struct SomeView: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
  @StateObject var myDataContainer = MyDataContainer()
  
  var body: some View {
     Text("Hello, world!")
       .onAppear { myDataContainer.context = managedObjectContext }
  }
}
```

Another approach that *does not* require `Optionals` is to use a wrapper view.

```
class MyDataContrainer: ObservableObject {
  @Published var foo: [Date] = []
  
  private let context: NSManagedObjectContext
  
  init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    self.context = context
    print("myDataContainer init")
  }
}

struct SomeViewWrapper: View {
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext

  var body: some View {
     SomeView(context: managedObjectContext)
  }
}

struct SomeView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var router: Router
  @StateObject var weeklyStatistics: MyDataContainer
  
  init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    _weeklyStatistics = StateObject(wrappedValue: StatisticsWeeklyDataContainer(context: context))
  }

  var body: some View { ... }
}
```

And then, of course, use `SomeViewWrapper` wherever you would've previously used `SomeView`

Comment: A variant to the wrapper view is to add @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) to the parent view and send the context as an argument to SomeView.init

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious, when we have an additional layer with view and pass the Env data to view, what performance implications we will face?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson -- thanks. That was what it was _supposed_ to do and somehow I didn't quite edit it enough...

Comment: @Nik I think very little overhead -- it's just creating one more `struct`, but you could benchmark it.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, `@Environment` variable can only be read in the body of a view. So, in order to initialise a `@State` object you can read the environment in a parent view, then pass it to your View in the body of that environment reader view:

```
struct EnvironmentReaderView: View {
    @Environment(\.myEnv) private var env
    
    var body: some View {
        MyView(value: env.value)
    }
}
```

Since you will encounter this "problem" quite frequently, you may consider to create a small generic helper view for this kind of task:

```
public struct EnvironmentReader<Content: View, Env>: View {
    @Environment private var env: Env

    private let content: (Env) -> Content

    public init(
        _ keyPath: KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, Env>,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Env) -> Content
    ) {
        self._env = .init(keyPath)
        self.content = content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        content(env)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
EnvironmentReader(\.myEnv) { env in
    MyView(value: env.value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious, when we have an additional layer with view and pass the Env data to view, what performance implications we will face?

Comment: Chances are, that when you separate views to perform only one specific task, your code may become faster, since the body function depends on less variables and can get skipped if these haven't changed.